# I need to print out specific alphabet from input single word

Tags: python

So if selected alphabet is a,b,c

```
letter = (a,b,c)  
words = input(“enter any single word”)

a is x # x is shape1  
b is y # y is shape2  
c is z # z is shape3
```

So if user enters input like “apple”, print out “x” because “apple” contains only “a” from selected alphabet.

If user enters input to “banana”, print out “yxxx” because it has baaa from banana.

Can anyone help me out on this problem? And how to make this code work properly?

Also, if user enters “kiwi”, it should print message “invalid please try again” with new input box. How to make this one?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not really a hard problem., and you are required to make a good faith attempt before asking for help.

Comment: Please read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: How would you solve this as a human?  You would go through the input string letter by letter.  If this letter is found in your "from" set, then you would write down the corresponding letter in the "to" set.  At the end, if you didn't write down anything, you return your error.  That's exactly how you write the code.

Comment: Be thankful Tim Roberts chose to help you, most people would not have wasted time holding your hand to step over a puddle without you even trying it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
shapes = {‘a’: ‘x’, ‘b’: ‘y’, ‘c’: ‘z’}
while true:
    words = input(“enter any single word”)
    output = “”.join([shapes[letter] for letter in words if letter in shapes])
    if output:
        print(output)
        break
    else:
        print(“invalid please try again”)
```

Please improve the formatting of your question.